# Dask - How do I set dtypes after reading csv without knowing them before hand?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have csv files (cannot be any other format unfortunately) that I need to read into my program that should perform some manipulation on the data using Dask (dask==2023.5.0) for Pandas.

The issue I am having is any time I try to call `my_df.set_index('Date')`, `my_df.compute()` or similar, I get

```
'Mismatched dtypes found in `pd.read_csv`/`pd.read_table`.\n\n+------------+--------+----------+\n| Column     | Found  | Expected |\n+------------+--------+----------+\n| TextFields | object | float64  |\n+------------+--------+----------+\n\nThe following columns also raised exceptions on conversion:\n\n- TextFields\n  ValueError(\'could not convert string to float: "{\\\'Text\\\': \\\'userKilled\\\', \\\'DeleteReason\\\': \\\'Canceled by User\\\'}"\')\n\nUsually this is due to dask\'s dtype inference failing, and\n*may* be fixed by specifying dtypes manually by adding:\n\ndtype={\'TextFields\': \'object\'}\n\nto the call to `read_csv`/`read_table`.'
```

The traceback is reasonable, but I cannot use the suggested fix, since I do not know which offending columns will exist in any file, the next may include a different column (or any number of columns) that are incorrectly inferred.

I have also confirmed that stripping the whitespace does not help. Increasing the sample bytes also does not help infer.

```
import re
import dask.dataframe as ddf

df = ddf.read_csv(
    "/home/me/Downloads/my_messy_file.csv", sample=2500000000
)


types = {"float64": float}

# try and compute, until we resolve all dtypes
can_compute = False
while not can_compute:
    try:
        df.compute()
        can_compute = True
    except ValueError as err:
        # probably a better way to do this, but it does get the results I expect for now.
        fields = re.search(
            r"Expected \|.*\| (\w+) \| (\w+) \| (\w+)  \|",
            err.args[0].replace("\n", ""),
        )
        if fields:
            field, found, expected = fields.groups()

            # have tried without the dictionary as well, just trying 'float64'
            # have also tried df[field] = df[field].astype(expected)
            df = df.astype({field: types[expected] if expected in types else expected})

            print(field, found, expected)
print('I made it!')
```

I expect it to get to the final print, after successfully computing. However, I am getting the error above each time, and it appears to not set df with the new type, since the print out continuously yields `TextFields object float64` infinitely.